# How to create a non-modal React dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nwjs, non-modal

I'm working on a javascript [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)-based application running under [nwjs](https://nwjs.io/).

My task is: on a button click, display scrollable instructions in a dialog that users can drag to a second monitor, so they can do their work in the main window, following the instructions in my new dialog.

I only know how to make modal dialogs with React.  How do I make a non-modal dialog, so the user can scroll through the instructions as needed while they work in the main window?

Comment: You can open a new window; you can't drag HTML out of the browser.

Comment: Thanks - based on your comment, I'm looking at [nwjs Window.open](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#windowopenurl-options-callback) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window you create trought react, must stay in browser window.

Call new child window so you get new window that can be dragged across 
desktop.

```
Window.open(url, [options], [callback])
```

[See documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#windowopenurl-options-callback)

Comment: Thanks - do you know where to find a small sample app that demonstrates showing a react component in the new window?

Comment: No, but you can load any URL into new vidow, with new react instances, you can propagate events maybe trought local storage or trought ipcRenderer -> ipcMain -> ipcRenderer(another) ... maybe events in local storage are acessible from each window of electron browser, otherwise there is no simple way to propage events across different browser windows.